# Fluentd tail log4j files setup

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j, kibana, fluentd

We have a Java based enterprise application which produces logs using log4j and we want to use Fluentd with Elasticsearch and Kibana as described [here](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/free-alternative-to-splunk-by-fluentd). 
I want to configure Fluentd to forward our existing logs and not use a new logger. I believe we want to use `type tail` for that so we can point Fluentd to the right files but I think we need some examples on how to configure the `td-agent.conf` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Fluentd has an input plugin called : [in_tail](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail)

> The in_tail Input plugin allows Fluentd to read events from the tail
>   of text files. Its behavior is similar to the tail -F command.

You can configure it to parse your log by providing a format regex based on your logging schema.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Below td-agent.conf for apache access log. Change **format** as per your log format in parser.rb. In my case parser.rb in /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.7/lib/fluent/parser.rb

```
<source>
 @type tail
 format apache
 tag apache.access
 path /var/log/httpd/access_log
</source>


<match apache.access>
 type stdout
</match>
```

stdout is print output in td-agent.log. so first make sure about it prints the tail of your log file in td-agent.log. after getting success you replace match tag whatever you want.

Have a Good Luck